# Front end собеседование

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, html

Подкиньте пару вопросов с собеседования на должность front end из вашего личного опыта. Все, что было доступно в интернете, я уже нашел. Хотелось бы именно из вашего личного опыта. Благодарю!

Comment: var option = new Option() )))

Answer (score 10):

Задаю простенькие задачи:

- http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/36Jve/
- http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/5jaHB/
- http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/YBSTX/
- http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/ZSd3w/
- http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/kQ8fX/

по ходу решения которых спрашиваю, почему именно так сделал, какие ещё есть способы решения.

И ещё:

- Подходы/методологии написания CSS?
- GruntJS, Bower, npm — для чего используются?
- RequireJS (или подобные) — зачем нужен?
- Тестирование: какие библиотеки знаешь (+/-), что использовал?
- Как логировать JS ошибки с клиента, какие "подводные" камни?
- Какие фреймворки знает/использовал (если не использовал, то почему), как они устроены внутри.

P.S. Также до собеседования, можно посмотреть акаунт на github.

Comment: простые и интересные задачки )

Comment: Они и должны быть простыми, если человек в "теме", усложняйте пример и смотрите как кандидат будет его править. Пример может быть совершенно любым, например: Как вывести "WAT" 12 раз? (перечеслите все способы, которые сможете придумать, даже самые безумные)

Comment: По мне так очень легкие задачи по жс :)

Решив их, реально можно получить работу? О_О

Comment: Нет, но решив их я с вами продолжу разговор :] Поверьте, это фильтр, которым можно отсечь очень многих. Основной упор, это именно вопросы из "Еще", там большой фронт для разговора.

Comment: был как то на собеседовании, где опрашивали сразу несколько человек, давали поочереди простенькие логические задачки, типо "сколько теннисных мячей помещается в автобус", так вот некоторые настолько глупые (нелогичные) ответы давали, или не давали... В общем простые задачи могут отсеять людей явно не в теме, а кто в тебе способны обучаться )

Comment: какие есть подходы методологии написания сss? SASS? О чем речь? Модульность? Какие подводные камни логирования JS ошибок?

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, Методология, это: BEM, OOCSS, SMACSS и другие. Логирование ошибок: как, основная проблема onerror, что не так размещением скриптов на стороннем домене, какие системы логирования есть, приходилось ли их использовать и т.п. Это всё устные вопросы.

Comment: Извините за мою безграмотность, но как во втором примере сравнивать два разных объекта?

Comment: @lampa, там не нужно сравнить два разных объекта, нужно чтобы это был один и тотже объект, обновил пример: http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/5jaHB/

Comment: Играючи решил всё, а забуксовал на [этом](http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/5jaHB/ 'jsFiddle').  
Какое решение, скажите на милость?

Answer (score 7):

По верстке спрашивали:
Как прижать футер к низу окна браузера?
Как выровнять по центру блок с фиксированной шириной? (`margin: 0 auto`)
Чему равна высота блока, если у него задано `float: left`? (0)
Как сделать очищение потока при использовании элементов с `float` ? (через `oveflow: hidden` или через псевдоэлемент `after` [How to avoid empty clear divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874877/how-to-avoid-empty-clear-divs))
Какие новые теги разметки появились в html5? (`header`, `section`, `article`, `aside` и тд), рассказать немного в каких случаях какой тег используется.

Если еще чего вспомню, то в комментах допишу.

Comment: Честно говоря, что-то слишком уж простоватые вопросы вам попались на собеседовании.

Comment: Да, это халява, конечно, для juniorа вопросы .

Answer (score 6):

- Что будет если не указать doctype. ( quirks mode )
- Как сделать одинаковые по высоте колонки.
- Как сделать так чтобы по центру ( по ширине ) располагались квадраты (блоки) и при уменьшение окна если последний не помещается в ряд, то он перескакивал на следующую строчку и становится по центру. ( display: inline-block для квадратов + text-align:center для div-обёртки ).

Comment: Как сделать одинаковые по высоте колонки?

Comment: Сейчас существует куча техник и перечислить их все тут будем слишком долго. Если вам интересно, то погуглите по запросу "колонки одинаковой высоты css".

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/4-metoda-sozdaniya-kolonok-odinakovoy-vysoty

Answer (score 5):

Реализовать onclick, чтобы вызвалась функция которую передали и те что были присвоены до этого.

Реализовать is-a наследование, ооп все функции и публичные свойства должны наследоваться.

Ещё спрашивали как сделть чтобы при изменении записи в БД сразу отображались данные в табличке.

И как вычислить высоту всего документа.

Только это без jquery.

Comment: "те, что были до этого" - не совсем понятно.

Фунция переданная онклику? - сам хандлер или калбэк хандлера?

Comment: Можно несколько раз вызывать onclick с передачей параметра - функции обработчика. Должны вызываться подряд все, как бы. По цепочке.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/33B5g/ как тут.

Comment: Это вопросы для джуниора или мидла?

Comment: @Archiolidius, не для junior а

Answer (score 5):

Важным вопросом считаю оптимизацию клиентской части. Хорошо, если чесловек не только разбирается в нужных front-end технологиях, но также знает, какими способами можно ускорить загрузку страниц/контента и соответственно уменьшить время ожидания пользоватетелей. Этого списка будет более чем достаточно: [High Performance Web Sites](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/rules.php)

Answer (score 2):

Какой цвет будет иметь текст в теге, приведенном ниже? Как изменить результат на противоположный?

```
<style>
    #color {
        color: red;
    }
    .color {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
<div class="color" id="color">Текст</div>
```

Comment: Как изменить результат? Поменять цвета местами:)

Comment: Нее... мне задавали этот вопрос на собеседовании. Правильный ответ был либо style="color: blue;" либо .color{color: blue !important;}

Comment: того кто задавал с такими "правильными" ответами самого сцаными тряпками из индустрии. http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector

Comment: @Андрей Таланин, та это ясно, я думал ничего не надо добавлять сюда.

Answer (score 0):

Даю небольшую, но реальную задачу из текущего проекта. В процессе возникает множество вопросов и динамика взаимодействия помогает определить, подходит ли данный конкретный человек в данном конкретном проекте прямо сейчас.